# understanding of urlpatterns in urls.py of Django App

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Problem: When we try to add the data to the database. So, the request will always come to this URL starting with the project-level directory, `todo_main`. So here, we will create a pattern.

`path('todo/', include('todo.urls'))`,

This path will forward the request to todo. URLs.

```
from django.urls import path
from  .import views

urlpatterns =[
    path('addTask/', views.addTask, name='addTask'),
]
```

So whenever we send a request to add a task, then the corresponding `views.addTask` should run, which will be a task.

Questions:
I try to understand my best what is the meaning or purpose of `addTask`. Can we write another word instead of it?

Comment: By `addTask` do you mean the one in `'addTask/'` or `views.addTask` or the one in `name='addTask'`? All three can be different by the way and don't need to be the same name.

Comment: `addTask` is just a name that the programmer made up, to describe the function of the view.  Presumably this app deals with things named "tasks", and the function of that specific view is to create a new task.

Comment: And yes, you can write another word if you like.  You can call it `cheeseburger`.  Or `paperclip`.  Or anything you want.  But any programmer who looks at this code might find those names confusing...

Comment: you can use any name you want ,it’s a good practice  to always use `namespaced` URL in your `url.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to name argument, it can be whatever you want.

`name=` argument can differ from endpoint name (`"addTask/"` here), the main goal of it is to be distinct and tell programmer which path it is just by name.

This argument is useful when you wanna find url pattern somewhere else in your code, for example when using `reverse()` from `django.urls`

Here's documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns